# Showing that End$_{FG}V$ is isomorphic to $F$ as a ring.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, modules, ring-isomorphism, division-ring

Let $G$ be a finite group, $F$ be an algebraically closed field, and $V$ an
irreducible $FG$-module.  I want to show that End$_{FG}V$ is isomorphic to $F$ as a ring.

I managed to get that End$_{FG}V$ is a division ring by Shur's lemma, and that under composition End$_{FG}V$ is a field, but I am struggling to finish the proof off.  I think that there may be something to do with $F$ being algebraically closed that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $V$ is simple (irreducible), it is finite-dimensional over $F$. Then $\mathop{\rm End}_{FG}(V)$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $F$. But $F$ being algebraically closed implies that any such algebra is $1$-dimensional, and thus isomorphic to $F$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Why does $F$ being algebraically closed mean that any finite dimensional division algebra over $F$ must be one-dimensional?

Comment: Suppose $D\supsetneq F$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra. Then, for any $\alpha\in D\setminus F$, we have a finite extension of fields $F(\alpha)/F$, which must be algebraic. This is a contradiction.